# Trying to receive bitmap string from server

Tags: php, android, bitmap

I'm uploading a String bitmap as "User profile image". The upload to the server using php is all good, and the download from the server too. The thing is when I'm looking in the bitmap String I see little arrows and i don't know why is this happening.

String bitmap I'm sending (post encoded): [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Qoh.png)

and the string bitmap i'm receiving(pre decoded): [2] I PAST IT INTO THE COMENTS BECAUSE I'M NEW HERE AND THEY DON'T LET ME TO PUT MORE THAN 1 LINK

I think maybe I'm not dealing ok reading the string from the php. If needed i can paste the code where I do it.

Thanks for the help guys!

[EDIT]

code to receive my string from the php:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + "");
        }
        line = sb.toString();
```

Once I split the line by the commas: (im receiving smth like"name":"john","age"="5",...,"bitstringImag"="/9j/4AA.." )

Im getting the Bitmap String value:

```
String[] bitmstrIn = kvPairs[5].split(":"); //separating the key from the value
            String[] bitmstrIn2 = bitmstrIn[1].split("\\}");  //erasing last key in the String
            String bitStr = bitmstrIn2[0].replaceAll("\"", ""); //removing the added (i dont know why) backslash.
            String biStrFin = bitStr.replaceAll("\\\\","");//removing the added (i dont know why) backslash.
```

and the result in bitStrFin is the one I pasted in to the comments.

thanks!

Comment: [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tf81o.png

Comment: Are you sure that not just your IDE applying word-wrapping/visualization? - Does it actually decode ok?

Comment: looks like word wrap when you are trying to debug the variable or may be some special charaters are present in the string which are considered as new line chars

Comment: I think this is IDE markup for wrapping single line

Comment: So, you guys  think there is no problem to try to decode the bitstring bitmap? I dont think the way i'm reading it from the php is not the best way to do it. I will edit my question to show you, if you guys have any idea to improve it i will be very happy!

Comment: What is a `String bitmap` ? Never heard of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a similar approach to receive images from a PHP server on Android using the [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bin2hex.php) function on server-side. Let's see the code:

After getting the hex string of JSON, we convert it to a ByteArray:

```
/**
 * Converts a hexadecimal string to byte array.
 *
 * @param s String to convert.
 * @return The result of conversion.
 */
 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
 }
```

Then create a new Bitmap from the ByteArray:

```
/**
 * Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array.
 *
 * @param data byte array of compressed image data
 * @param offset offset into imageData for where the decoder should begin parsing.
 * @param length the number of bytes, beginning at offset, to parse
 * @return The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.
 */ 
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

The result Bitmap can be loaded into a ImageView using the `imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` method.